# web api start html page

Tags: html, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have web api project and I have *.html page and I need run it after run my project but I don't know how do it.
In MVC I use **MapRoute** like this:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

But I don't know how do it in web api. I have next routes config:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

and how to add other config for run my html page?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Like this code into the WebApi project:

```
public class DefaultController : ApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Default controller for render swagger UI 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet, Route("")]
        public RedirectResult Index()
        {
            var requestUri = Request.RequestUri;
            return Redirect(requestUri.AbsoluteUri + "swagger/ui/index");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This code how you add new routing:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "ApiWithAction",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );

     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Now just write route to your static file

Comment: Thnaks, but how to render html page. Somethink like this return View("Index.html"); ? In web api

Comment: Oh, ....It is bad idea. API build for return data. If you try return view - probably you have bad architecture. You can try some tricks in google, but again - it is bad idea.

Comment: Not problem. Good luck!!